# How can I make Text to Speech use different voices for different languages?

Tags: macos, text-to-speech, automation

I am learning French and sometimes need to use Text to Speech to fix my pronunciation. As English is my second language, I also sometimes use Text to Speech with it.

The problem is that the English voices do not have correct French pronunciation, and vice versa. I have to open System Preferences to switch between the two every time.

How can I automatically switch between the voices according to the language of the text selected to be spoken? If there is no way to do that, how would do it using Automator/AppleScript?

Comment: Here is possible answer from a sister forum:

http://superuser.com/questions/468130/mac-os-x-quickly-change-voices-for-text-to-speech

Comment: If someone finds a way to detect the language automatically, it could also be posted as an answer to the questions linked above.

Comment: Didn't know it was a duplicate. Teaches you how much tagging your question correctly is important.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible answer from another forum:

https://superuser.com/questions/468130/mac-os-x-quickly-change-voices-for-text-to-speech

Comment: On Ask Different and all other Stack Exchange sites, you have to be that "someone" while answering questions.

Comment: @duci9y It is also important when you ask a question to tell people what you already know.  I will fix it for you.

Comment: I quote from my original question, "How can I **automatically** switch between the voices according to the language of the text selected to be spoken? If there is no way to do that, how would do it using Automator/AppleScript?"

Comment: Hasn't the last part of your question been answered now?